# Angular - How to filter (search) data from multiple properties of data (fields)?

Tags: angular, pipes-filters

I'm getting my data through API. I want to create filtering and searching on the data.
I've created a pipe and it has the following code:

File: `text-search.pipe.ts`

```
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any {
    if (!items) return [];

    if (!searchText) return items;
    console.log("ITEMS ARE",items);
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();


    return items.filter(it => {
        return it.hospital_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });

  }
```

My `component.html` file is as follows:

The input field //User can search by name

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

And then the pipe is applied to:

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let hospital of hospital_list | hospitalSearch: searchText; let i = index;">
```

**Question:** 
If I have another input field or several other fields such as City Field where the user can search through City, Specialization etc as well?

For e.g. :

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchCity" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

So how do I modify the existing pipe? Or would I have to create a new pipe.

**Things I've tried:**
In `pipe.ts` file:

```
transform(items: any[], searchText: string, searchCity?: string): any {
    if (!items) return [];

    if (!searchText) return items;
    console.log("ITEMS ARE",items);
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    if (!searchCity) return items;
    console.log("ITEMS ARE",items);
    searchCity= searchCity.toLowerCase();


    return items.filter(it => {
        return it.hospital_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
        return it.hospital_city.toLowerCase().includes(searchCity);

    });
```

It doesn't work since the 2nd return statement is un-reachable. I have tried to read the API I didn't find any support. Kindly guide me how to add multiple field search filtering to the data I'm getting. Thank You. 
      }

Comment: This isn't related to answering your question, but I think your short-circuits are incorrect in your final `pipe` implementation. You'll likely only want to return `items` if _both_ of the search terms are falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean operator here. You will need to choose which one is most appropriate for your particular filtering use case.

**Filter items that match at least one of:**

```
return items.filter(it => {
    return it.hospital_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        || it.hospital_city.toLowerCase().includes(searchCity);
});
```

**Filter items that match all:**

```
return items.filter(it => {
    return it.hospital_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        && it.hospital_city.toLowerCase().includes(searchCity);
});
```

To invoke your pipe with multiple arguments, use another `:`.

```
*ngFor="let hospital of hospital_list | hospitalSearch: searchText:searchCity"
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I include my 2nd variable: searchCity in html where I've applied the pipe on ngFor loop:  <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let hospital of hospital_list | hospitalSearch: searchText; let i = index;">